# Which to use? Delegate vs. keyPathObserver - UIViewController With Two UIScrollViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, delegates

Before I get too far in to implementing this, I wanted to know what the optimal way to implement doing things with regards to contentOffest as the UIScrollView gets moved.

NOTE: Asking this from having read that having more than one object calling a delegate method can be problematic

1) Adding observers to each of the views' contentOffset keyPaths

2) Making my class a UIScrollViewDelegate and using scrollViewDidScroll

```
class MyAwesomeVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollViewA: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollViewB: UIScrollView!
private var observerContext = 0

...

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         scrollViewA.delegate = self
         scrollViewB.delegate = self

         scrollViewA.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", options: .new, context: &observerContext)
         scrollViewB.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", options: .new, context: &observerContext)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        // check which scrollview if possible then do all the things

    }


    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

                 // check which scrollview if possible then do all the things

    }

    ...
    deinit {
        scrollViewA.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", context: &observerContext)
        scrollViewB.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", context: &observerContext)
        scrollViewA = nil
        scrollViewB = nil
    }


}
```

Comment: This is a somewhat opinion based question (so it might get closed) but option 2 is much simpler and requires much less code.

Comment: I was looking over this without having the rest of my code in the way, and had a kind of ancillary question - are delegate methods like scrollViewDidScroll already triggered from keyPathObservers?

I only asked because when looking it up, there were claims that using the delegate method with more than one object calling it can get messy.

Comment: The delegate and KVO have nothing to do with each other. But there's no point in implementing both here. Since a delegate method exists for your needs, using KVO is pointless. Inside the delegate method you can simply compare the `scrollView` parameter against your two outlet properties to know which scroll view has been scrolled. Very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the cleanest way to do this is to just assign yourself as the scroll view delegate and override the function `scrollViewDidScroll` like you have, and `print(scrollView.contentOffset)` in the function, and do whatever you need with it. If you need to check if you're scrolling down, you can attach a property to your class that saves your last contentOffset and simply compare it to the current one.